# Looking for descriptions and guidance on the use of advanced Socket Options

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm refactoring some old Socket routines and I'm struggling to make sense of some more advanced Socket Options (*specifically `System.Net.Sockets.SocketOptionName`*) and the implications of removing/adding them.

***For Example**... DontRoute, OutOfBandInline, SendLowWater/ReceiveLowWater, DontFragment, BlockSource, NoDelay, NoChecksum, etc...*

A full list can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketoptionname.aspx

Can anyone recommend a source where I can get more detailed guidance/descriptions on socket options? Although my focus relates to the overall performance of the sockets, I'm also interested in gaining some context with regard to the appropriateness of various options under different circumstances.

Comment: Are you still working on this? I implemented TCP/IP sockets in C.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented sockets between Windows system and VxWorks. I believe I used this as a start @ [Code at CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17031/A-Network-Sniffer-in-C).
CodeProject site has a history of legacy codes.

I just found out Wikipedia has full sample code on TCP/IP sockets with explanations! It's at [BSD Sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets)

Answer (score 1):

The advanced socket APIs are not well documented on the .NET side of MSDN. You have to look in the unmanaged side.

Fortunately, the low-level `Socket` class and its associated enums are almost a 1:1 mapping to the unmanaged functions/values. e.g., [here's the listing of meanings for the `setsockopt` values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740525%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).